# Strikethrough associated cells when value in column changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet that has three columns:
 **employee number** 
**employee name** 
**availability** 
What I am trying to do is when the **availability** value changes from a number to nothing the **employee number** and the **employee name** associated with that row gets a strikethrough. 
Also when an **availability number** is added the strikethrough disappears. 
I have written some code below but I have no idea if I am going in the right direction.

```
Sub change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim watchrange As Range
dim intersectrange as range

Set ws = Worksheets("Workbench Report")

endrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Set watchrange = Range("E2:E" & endrow)
Set intersectrange = Intersect(Target, watchrange)
If intersectrange = "" Then
ws.Range("B" & rng.Row).Resize(1, 2).Font.Strikethrough = True
Else
'do nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Could someone help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

This worksheet event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim watchrange As Range, r As Range, rw As Long
    Dim intersectrange As Range, endrow As Long

    endrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set watchrange = Range("C2:C" & endrow)
    Set intersectrange = Intersect(Target, watchrange)
    If intersectrange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each r In intersectrange
        rw = r.Row
        If r.Value = "" Then
            Range("A" & rw & ":B" & rw).Font.Strikethrough = True
        Else
            Range("A" & rw & ":B" & rw).Font.Strikethrough = False
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

will meet your needs.  You need to adjust the columns to match your data schema.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**EDIT#1:**

This code is triggered by changes to column **C** and reside in the worksheet code area for that sheet.

If your button code changes those column **C** values, then this event code would work with it.

Comment: So if I was running this code from a command button that already has code withing its click event could I turn this code into a public sub and call it in the command button event?

Comment: @BriannaCates  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: The only issue I have with that is that the excel workbook that is holding my code is pulling the worksheet that I want to be able to altar so the code would be removed every time a new sheet is added

Comment: @BriannaCates  If your button code is performing the column **C** changes, then have it also perform the column **A** and **B** format changes and forget about using an event macro.

Comment: I got it to work by just making it a sub and calling it under my command button but your code worked perfect! Thanks so much :)

Comment: One more question though... Im sorry but what if the availability column already has nothing in it?.. What I want is just the changes... if its already nothing then I dont want the strike through, I just want the strike through to happen if the value changes to nothing not if it already is zero. Does that make sense?

Comment: @BriannaCates  My code will not react to a **zero** in column **C**, only the entry of a **blank** in column **C**

Comment: Some of the value are already blank that I do not want to get a strikethrough

Comment: @BriannaCates  My code should only react to ***changes*** to blank not cells that ***are*** blank.

Comment: Oh hmm when I run it it is turning the ones that are already blank are getting a strikethrough.. maybe I have something wrong

Comment: @BriannaCates  It is the nature of the Event macro to only process those cells that have changed.

Comment: I think that maybe the way I converted it into a regular sub and have that procedure called through the button in whats making it not work but I do not know how to put it any other way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106486/discussion-between-brianna-cates-and-garys-student).